# simple gui/webapp for datascience in python that doesnt rerun the script everytime

Tags: python, user-interface, data-science

Hi im searching for a way to make a GUI or local webapp for datascience with python.

I have a certain workflow for up 50 datasets where I have to adjust certain settings for every dataset individualy.

Explanation: I am doing Data Analysis on Lightcurves(Light Flux over Time) from TESS. So i have a code bit that reads in my data from a file and then produces the important arrays that i can then plot.(This is one of the parts of the code i dont want to have to rerun every time). Then i have a plot of the Lightcurves without any manipulation (again see above). Then im doing abit of manipulation by so called detrending so I have a general trend curve with adjustable parameters(This is the part where it needs to be rerun to compute the new curves) and then I subtract those curves from each other. After this come some similar steps where again i have Plots of Curves where i adjust a few bits here and there.

I started doing this with Streamlit but the problem is streamlit reruns the entire script every time which costs me alot of time. Is there something that is rather simple like streamlit(I am not deploying this just for myself and possibly a small amount of other scientists) but doesn't need to rerun the whole script every time i change something.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Added Explanation about the Workflow, hope the explanation is understandable und not too physical.

Answer (score 0):

Well this is a very very broad question so I ll give a broad answer. I dont know eactly what you want to build but why not just use Jupyter notebook?

You can create a web like application with voila library by simply running your notebook with voila.

Comment: maybe see a comparison of visualization libraries here : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mZOIeOeswB0

Comment: Jupyter is too much in depth for what i want to do. I want to drag and drop a file in and have it run through some algorithms and then change a few parameters at a few points and then rerun only the parts where the parameters changed. Which yes i can do with Jupyter but i dont want to have code involved for the user. That defeats the point of having a GUI.